# UITableViewContraller class in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hi can some body give me some idea I need a to Create a NSOblect Class for tableView cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Basically I want to create a nsobject class and create a class method/Instance method for this delegate method and after that call this class/instance method to any of the table view in any class. just like how we create method and used in different class.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like (not positive though) you want a custom `UITableViewCell`? Here is a good tutorial for that(that also goes over other basics of UITableViews): [here](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/). You can also Google for Custom UITableViewCell or similar for other help.